# jquery: mouseout event firing even after I used a click event to hide the div

Tags: jquery, click, hide, jquery-animate, mouseout

```
jQuery("#na").mouseover(function()
{
    jQuery("#na").animate({width:"325px", height:"203px", left:"-40px", top:"-25px"}, 200)
});

jQuery("#na").mouseout(function()
{
    jQuery("#na").stop()
    jQuery("#na").animate({width:"244px",height:"152px", left:0, top:0}, 200)
});

jQuery("#na").click(function()
{
    jQuery("#na").hide()
    jQuery("#back").show()
});
```

so thats my code, the problem is when the click event is triggered all is fine, na dissapears but the moment you move your mouse it reappers again. I figured the problem is that the mouseout event is being triggered, but for the life of me cant figure out how to fix it. any ideas?

Comment: I have set this up for you but I cannot replicate the error. Do you want to check it and tell me if everything looks okay? http://jsfiddle.net/hJgmV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the mouseout method, check if the "na" is visible or hidden. If it is hidden, dont do anything, else you can do the animate.

EDIT:

Try your mouseout method like this:

```
jQuery("#na").mouseout(function(){
    if(jQuery("#na").is(":visible")){
       jQuery("#na").stop()
       jQuery("#na").animate({width:"244px",height:"152px", left:0, top:0}, 200)
    }
});
```

Comment: whats the argument for visible?

Comment: Edited my answer. Try something like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery("#na").click(function(e)
{   
    e.stopPropagation();
    jQuery("#na").hide()
    jQuery("#back").show()
});
```

I am not sure if this would work.. Theoretically this should stop the propogation of the mous ent but i am not sure if it only stop the click event being propogated!